# I want to make my menu selected everytime it is clicked and changes the pages with selected menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select, navigation

I have this jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  


//Default Action

$(".navigation li:first").addClass("selectedli").show(); //Activate first tab


//On Click Event

$(".navigation li").click(function() {
$(".navigation li").removeClass("selectedli"); //Remove any "active" class

$(this).addClass("selectedli"); //Add "active" class to selected tab

});



});

</script>
```

and css is as follows

```
 .selectedli a {background: #3a73ba; color:#fff; cursor:default;}
```

and menu is written as

```
<div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <!--<li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m1')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">About Us</a>
        <div id="m1" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()"> <a href="inner_page.html">Member Profile</a> <a href="inner_page.html">Message from MD</a> <a href="inner_page.html">History</a> </div>
      </li>-->
        <li class="selectedli"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="inner_index.php">2nd Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="inner2.php">Third Page</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
```

but when I click the link and navigate to "inner_index.php" the first `li` is selected whereas I want to select the second `li`. What should I do?

Comment: Your script is always "activating" first tab, and i take it you're loading this script on each page?

Comment: How do you know what page you are on? Really it would be best to remove the default action, and instead put the 'active' class in the html of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
:second
```

or

```
:eq(1)
```

So

```
$(".navigation li:first").addClass("selectedli").show(); //Activate first tab
```

will become

```
$(".navigation second").addClass("selectedli").show(); //Activate first tab
```

Comment: Can you add an example, relating to the OP's code, of how to use these?